# Why is 'True or False' faster than 'False or True'?

Tags: python, optimization, time, boolean

I ran the code

```
a = True
b = False
c = False
d = False
e = False
import time
iterations = int(1e6)
start = time.time()
for _ in range(iterations):
    a or b or c or d or e
print(time.time() - start)
start = time.time()
for _ in range(iterations):
    b or c or d or e or a
print(time.time() - start)
```

Results

```
0.10876178741455078
0.26296424865722656
```

- Why does the order of boolean evaluation make a difference in speed?
- Is it because of some form of optimization?
- If so is there a resource I can read?

Comment: `or` short-circuits as soon as it hits `True`.

Comment: totally unrelated but if you may want to learn about the stdlib's `timeit` module...

Comment: @ajcr short-circuit. I did not know about that. Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is because of [short-circuiting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation):

```
True or WHATEVER # always True
```

In the first expression `a` which is `True` comes first and there is no need to proceed.

A cool way to show this is using an piece of code that is never run because of short-circuiting:

```
>>> def _print():
...     print "no short circuit"
...
>>> True or _print()
True
>>> False or _print()
no short circuit
```

Answer (score 2):

Because `or` evaluates lazily, and if it finds `True` there are no more checks needed; while if the first one is `False` then it has to evaluate the next expression until `True` is found or there no more checks.